# I can't convert a JSON file into a table inside Excel

Tags: json, excel, powerquery

I'm trying to convert a JSON file into Excel table.
To give context, the JSON file contains reviews from Steam downloaded through Steam Reviews (https://pypi.org/project/steamreviews/).
When I import the JSON using the Data menu and PowerQuery, I get empty tables.

PowerQuery Add Table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ghrGV.png

Excel table with no data from JSON
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUIXm.png

Actual review data in JSON
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKvc.png

I clicked on the "In Table" option in PowerQuery, clicked on Convert and Close/Load but I still can see only the Value cell filled with generic Record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to expand the records in powerquery

In general, here is sample code

```
let Source = {[ a = 1, b = 2 ] , [ c = 3 ] , [ a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ]},
#"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error) ,
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( #"Converted to Table", "Column1"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Column1", ExpandList,ExpandList)
in Expand
```

[image]

or

```
let Source= #table({"Column1", "Column2"},{{"Apple",[ a = 1, b = 2 ]},{"Bear",[ c = 3 ]},{"Cat",[ a = 1, b = 2, c = 3 ]}}),
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column( Source, "Column2"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( Source, "Column2", ExpandList,ExpandList)
in Expand
```

[image]

**FOR SPECIFIC REQUIREMEMTS:**

```
let  Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Temp\review_304030 2.json")),
reviews = Source[reviews],
#"Converted to Table" = Record.ToTable(reviews),
ExpandList= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(#"Converted to Table", "Value"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( #"Converted to Table", "Value", ExpandList,ExpandList),
ExpandList2= List.Distinct(List.Combine(List.Transform(Table.Column(Expand, "author"), each if _ is record then Record.FieldNames(_) else {}))),
Expand2= Table.ExpandRecordColumn( Expand, "author", ExpandList2,ExpandList2)
in Expand2
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help.
I've now tried using expanding (using the interface) but still get null records and when I convert to table in Excel, I get only 3 empty rows.

https://i.imgur.com/aLtqFea.png

Hope this has more context.

Comment: Please try the code paste above, not code generated from the interface. They are not the same. Thanks

Comment: I've pasted the second code above still get null tables and no content:

https://imgur.com/a/wVtrYMN

I don't know what I'm doing wrong (new to PowerQuery, thank you for your patience).

Comment: At this point I am unsure of what you are doing, since you seem to be showing me the output of my own code.  The above code is a sample. It works if pasted into home ... advanced editor.  You then have to apply it to your situation, using your source and column names in place of my sample source and column names. Beyond this I cant help unless you feel like linking to your source data somehow

Comment: I've adjusted your code changing the names of the strings (e.g. Column2) to the ones in my archive (Values)

Yes, I can link the source data, no problem.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hC99tUW3VB1tuImjyLbSkXAIvjh7P8j-/view?usp=sharing